# Regex to ignore delimiter for certain parts of the data

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

## Current data and regex used

Consider the following data;

`FDTYP/TESTTYPE/FDPERIOD/31 Day(s)/MAT_INST/CREDIT_TO_ACC/DEPTACCT/0016/`

The current way used to separate the data is by using delimiter '/' to get this list of data;

`{"FDTYP", "TESTTYPE", "FDPERIOD", "31 Day(s)", "MAT_INST", "CREDIT_TO_ACC", "DEPTACCT", "0016" }`

and this is the code snippet with the regex used;

`REGEXP_SUBSTR( ORGDATA ,'(.*?)/|$', 1, COLUMN_VALUE, NULL, 1 ) AS DATALABEL`

---

## The problem

Now consider this data

`FDTYP/FD2323*/*/*-/FDPERIOD/31 Day(s)/MAT_INST/CREDIT_TO_ACC/DEPTACCT/0016/`

The second data contains the delimiter '/' which produces the following list of data

`{"FDTYP", "FD2323*", "*", "*-", "FDPERIOD", "31 Day(s)", "MAT_INST", "CREDIT_TO_ACC", "DEPTACCT", "0016" }`

when the correct data should be

`{"FDTYP", "FD2323*/*/*-", "FDPERIOD", "31 Day(s)", "MAT_INST", "CREDIT_TO_ACC", "DEPTACCT", "0016" }`

Now I know that the easiest way to fix this is by changing the delimiter used but unfortunately that is not possible because of legacy datas.

So is there any way to create a regex that ignore the delimiter for the second data?

I have tried the following regex

`(?<=FDTYP\/)(.*?)(?=\/FDPERIOD)`

and it does get me the second data but it does not work for the rest of the data.

Comment: This is going to be hard to handle using SQL regex.  You should normalize your data and bring the separate fields as columns into your table.

Comment: Replace the */ with something unique before splitting, then change it back afterward. Give more sample data if that's not the general format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% clear what version of SQL you are using or how you're actually getting that JSON, but assuming the problem spot always occurs between `FDTYPE/` and `/FDPERIOD`, I think something like this should work:

1. Replace only the instances of `/` in the substring with some character or character combo that you know won't occur in your dataset.  In my example I'm using `{!}` as the replacement.
2. Do you normal routine
3. Go back over extracted data and convert your replacement `{!}` back to `/`.

```sql
SELECT
    'FDTYP/FD2323*/*/*-/FDPERIOD/31 Day(s)/MAT_INST/CREDIT_TO_ACC/DEPTACCT/0016/' AS ORGDATA,
    CONCAT('FDTYP/', REPLACE(REGEXP_SUBSTR((SELECT ORGDATA), '(?<=FDTYP/)(.*)(?=/FDPERIOD)'), '/', '{!}'), REGEXP_SUBSTR((SELECT ORGDATA), '/FDPERIOD.*(?=/$)')) AS transformed,
    CONCAT('{"', REPLACE((SELECT transformed), '/', '", "'), '"}') AS object_str,
    REPLACE((SELECT object_str), '{!}', '/') AS untransformed
```

That gets you:

```
FDTYP/FD2323*/*/*-/FDPERIOD/31 Day(s)/MAT_INST/CREDIT_TO_ACC/DEPTACCT/0016/
FDTYP/FD2323*{!}*{!}*-/FDPERIOD/31 Day(s)/MAT_INST/CREDIT_TO_ACC/DEPTACCT/0016
{"FDTYP", "FD2323*{!}*{!}*-", "FDPERIOD", "31 Day(s)", "MAT_INST", "CREDIT_TO_ACC", "DEPTACCT", "0016"}
{"FDTYP", "FD2323*/*/*-", "FDPERIOD", "31 Day(s)", "MAT_INST", "CREDIT_TO_ACC", "DEPTACCT", "0016"}
```

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4BRg1FG23qhYYFrwFAqqEY/0

Comment: Thanks sir for your solution. As a side note, I use oracle SQL which does not support lookahead and lookbehind so i had to do something like this for the 1st step.

`'FDTYP/'||REPLACE(substr(ORGDATA, instr(ORGDATA, 'FDTYP/')+6, instr(ORGDATA, '/FDPERIOD')-7), '/','{!}')||substr(ORGDATA, instr(ORGDATA, '/FDPERIOD'))`

Answer (score 1):

In Oracle, you can use the regular expression `'^([^/]+)/(.*)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$'` and extract the capturing groups:

```sql
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(
         value,
         '^([^/]+)/(.*)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$',
         1,
         1,
         NULL,
         1
       ) AS col1,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR(
         value,
         '^([^/]+)/(.*)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$',
         1,
         1,
         NULL,
         2
       ) AS col2,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR(
         value,
         '^([^/]+)/(.*)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$',
         1,
         1,
         NULL,
         3
       ) AS col3,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR(
         value,
         '^([^/]+)/(.*)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$',
         1,
         1,
         NULL,
         4
       ) AS col4,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR(
         value,
         '^([^/]+)/(.*)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$',
         1,
         1,
         NULL,
         5
       ) AS col5,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR(
         value,
         '^([^/]+)/(.*)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$',
         1,
         1,
         NULL,
         6
       ) AS col6,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR(
         value,
         '^([^/]+)/(.*)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$',
         1,
         1,
         NULL,
         7
       ) AS col7,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR(
         value,
         '^([^/]+)/(.*)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$',
         1,
         1,
         NULL,
         8
       ) AS col8
FROM   table_name
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (value) AS
  SELECT 'FDTYP/FD2323*/*/*-/FDPERIOD/31 Day(s)/MAT_INST/CREDIT_TO_ACC/DEPTACCT/0016/' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'FDTYP/TESTTYPE/FDPERIOD/31 Day(s)/MAT_INST/CREDIT_TO_ACC/DEPTACCT/0016/' FROM DUAL
```

Outputs:

| COL1 | COL2 | COL3 | COL4 | COL5 | COL6 | COL7 | COL8 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| FDTYP | FD2323*/*/*- | FDPERIOD | 31 Day(s) | MAT_INST | CREDIT_TO_ACC | DEPTACCT | 0016 |
| FDTYP | TESTTYPE | FDPERIOD | 31 Day(s) | MAT_INST | CREDIT_TO_ACC | DEPTACCT | 0016 |

Or, to get the output as a single formatted string:

```sql
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(
         value,
         '^([^/]+)/(.*)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$',
         '{"\1", "\2", "\3", "\4", "\5", "\6", "\7", "\8"}'
       ) AS data
FROM   table_name;
```

Which outputs:

| DATA |
| --- |
| {"FDTYP", "FD2323*/*/*-", "FDPERIOD", "31 Day(s)", "MAT_INST", "CREDIT_TO_ACC", "DEPTACCT", "0016"} |
| {"FDTYP", "TESTTYPE", "FDPERIOD", "31 Day(s)", "MAT_INST", "CREDIT_TO_ACC", "DEPTACCT", "0016"} |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Q9NMxbhB)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following.

```java
(?<!\*)/
```

Output

```
FDTYP
TESTTYPE
FDPERIOD
31 Day(s)
MAT_INST
CREDIT_TO_ACC
DEPTACCT
0016


FDTYP
FD2323*/*/*-
FDPERIOD
31 Day(s)
MAT_INST
CREDIT_TO_ACC
DEPTACCT
0016
```